# Tesla spark gap causing touch lamps to turn on

Tags: rf, interference, tesla-coil

I have a [mini DIY Mini Tesla Coil Kit 15W Mini Music Tesla Coil Plasma Speaker](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/diy-kit-Mini-music-coil-plasma-speaker-speaker-science-experimental-technology-electronic-small-production-diy/32735383706.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10152_10065_10151_10130_10068_10344_10342_10343_10340_10341_10307_10060_10155_10154_10056_10055_10054_10059_10534_10533_10532_100031_10099_10338_10339_10103_10102_10052_10053_10142_10107_10050_10051_10324_10325_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10178_10110_10111_10112_10113_10114_10312_10313_10314_10078_10079_10073-10050,searchweb201603_12,ppcSwitch_5&btsid=76dccd45-734d-4975-8ddc-c351fce1f153&algo_expid=7b82988c-efc6-4f92-91f5-8b56c1c5b8fe-1&algo_pvid=7b82988c-efc6-4f92-91f5-8b56c1c5b8fe) and have noticed when I play various "complex" signals using it, it causes my capacitive touch lighting on the entertainment system in the living room to turn on (which is about 30 feet away).  Is there anyway to prevent this or at least figure out the correct signal to turn it off if my coil turns it on.  I did do a search but all I found was short explanations not how to figure out the correct signals that will turn it on or off. http://www.arrl.org/touch-lamp

Comment: Go outside with it.

Comment: Put a faraday cage around the system.

Comment: What do you expect from a device that is sparking all around.

Comment: "Is there any way to prevent this" -- stop using the tesla coil kit? It will always cause RF interference. That's practically its _purpose_.